HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage
While calling Google translation service API with .net7/.net 8, getting exception as
Error starting gRPC call.

HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from
HttpRequestMessage. (IP address:10159) InvalidOperationException:
Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage.", DebugException =
"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from
HttpRequestMessage.

 TranslationServiceClient client = TranslationServiceClient.Create();

 TranslateTextRequest request = new()
 {
     Contents = { stringsToTranslate },
     TargetLanguageCode = TargetLanguage,
     ParentAsLocationName = LocationName.FromProjectLocation(proejctId, "global"),

 };

 TranslateTextResponse response = client.TranslateText(request);


Not a .NET developer. It's possible (!?) that your client is unable to connect to the Translate service using the default gRPC (HTTP/2). Try switching to REST (HTTP1.1) to see whether that succeeds?
